# Initialize SVG.js in VueJS component

Tags: vue.js, svg.js

How to initialize [SVG.js](https://svgjs.dev/) in VueJS component and be able to use `SVG('drawing').size(300, 300)` ?

Answer (score 0):

`npm install svg.js`

OR

`yarn add svg.js`

In your app.js you can `require('svg.js');` or `import SVG from 'svg.js';`

This really should be all you need to begin using it.